# Sweat on body in Cycles

Tags: node-editor, glass

I'm trying to make sweat with particles, but Glass material creates very large shadow on skin & it produces black drops. I tried different settings, but either black drops, or reflections disappear, or no drops are visible. Please, can you tell me which nodes should be for realistic drops on body?

[image]

Comment: maybe try with a map? see the answer here: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-to-get-wet-skin-and-lips/1262283/2

Comment: Yes, I saw this tutorial, but I need drops.